# grade management in qt

Tags: c++, qt

My project is about grade management with QT, so I have a 'N' Student for input and the grade of each student, and for output I should give the Max and the Min also the average. This is the code I have written :

```
#include "gestion_des_notes.h"
#include "ui_gestion_des_notes.h"

Gestion_Des_Notes::Gestion_Des_Notes(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Gestion_Des_Notes)
{
      ui->setupUi(this);

      ui->label_2->setVisible(false);
      ui->line_Note->setVisible(false);
}

Gestion_Des_Notes::~Gestion_Des_Notes()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Gestion_Des_Notes::on_pushButton_clicked(){
   //hide the students total number request and show the point edit line and label
    ui->label->setVisible(false);
    ui->line_Enum->setVisible(false);
    ui->label_2->setVisible(true);
    ui->line_Note->setVisible(true);
   //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    int N = ui->line_Enum->text().toInt();
    int Num_Etud = ui->label_Etud->text().toInt();
    float Note_list [N];
    float Max = 0 ,Min = 9999,Sum = 0 ;

    if (Num_Etud < N){

        float Note = ui->line_Note->text().toInt();
        Note_list[Num_Etud] = Note;
        ui->label_Etud->setText(QString::number(Num_Etud+1));
    }

    //I think the Problem start here because every time i get a wrong max and min and average
   else {
       ui->pushButton->setEnabled(false);
       ui->line_Note->setText("***");
       for (int i=0 ; i <N ; i++){
            Sum += Note_list[i];
            if (Note_list[i] > Max) Max = Note_list[i];
            if (Note_list[i] < Min) Min = Note_list[i];
        }
        ui->line_Max->setText(QString::number(Max));
        ui->line_Min->setText(QString::number(Min));
        ui->line_Moy->setText(QString::number(Sum/N));
    }
}
```

Can you please help because I don't know where the problem is. I always get ( exponential something or a 0).

Answer (score 0):

The array `Note_list` contains random values when you compute the min, max and average. You are filling this array in the `if` statement, but using it in the `else`.

Comment: So what do you suggest as a solution ??

Comment: The rest of your code is not clear enough for me to provide you more help.